# How do I get the correct DateTime for a DateTimePicker in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, dst

Using the [DateTimePicker](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/date-time-picker) in Google Apps Script, I can have the user choose a date and time, and I can use [setTimeZoneOffsetInMins](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/date-time-picker#settimezoneoffsetinminstimezoneoffsetmins) to present a UTC date in the correct time zone.

The problem is that fixed timezones don't obey daylight savings time. I don't know before the user enters the date and time whether they'll be entering a time in EST or EDT, and so the timezone offset is guaranteed to be wrong for about half the year.

Is there a solution?

Comment: You should probably create a issue in issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

At the current stage, there is no direct method of achieving your task.

Just like suggested above, the best solution in this situation is to create a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) and provide all the necessary details.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Support](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features).